# Android view is not clickable in Fragment inside android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have this Relative layout which represent a button:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_login_login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_facebook"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >
```

this is button_facebook.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- question mark button drawable -->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_facebook_up" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_facebook_up" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_facebook_down" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_facebook_up"/>

</selector>
```

when attaching this layout to an activity, the behavior of the button works as expected.

When attaching to a fragment inside DrawerLayout - it doesn't work at all:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_menu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/pico_dark_blue"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"        
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15sp"
        android:paddingRight="15sp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Added:**

```
public class LoginFragment extends BasicFragment implements OnClickListener, Runnable{

    public static final String KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED = "expired";

    /**
     * The root {@link View} of the fragment
     */
    private View rootView;

    /**
     * The login button {@link View}
     */
    private View loginButton;

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_login;
    }

    @Override
    protected void findViews(View view) {
        this.rootView = view;
        loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_login_facebook_login);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setViews() {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }       

    @Override
    protected void onFinishedLoading() {
        Bundle args = getArguments();       
        //if this fragment was loaded after access token is expired - show the info window
        if (args != null && args.getBoolean(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED, false))
            showInfoWindow("Login expired\nPlease re-login to application", null, false, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //show info window
        showInfoWindow("Connecting to Facebook", null, true, false);
        //start login process
        getMainActivity().getFacebookManager().login(new FacebookConnectListener(this));        
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // when loading process if done - start the application
        getMainActivity().startApplication();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestComplete(JSONObject response) {

    }   
}
```

how can i solve it ?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: i didn't provide the xml...
look at the android:background="@drawable/button_facebook" this is supposed to change according to the click... but it doesn't

Comment: You need to provide the code for the `Fragment` as well as the `Activity` in which the `Fragment` is added.  Also, if you are hooking any type of `onClickListener` to the `main_activity_fragment` layout within the `Activity`.

Comment: done, added the fragment